# Return a result even if Select is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I have this query :

`SELECT p.id, p.name, p.img, p.template_usage, t.name as tpl_name FROM platforms as p, xml_template as t WHERE p.template_usage = t.id`

It returns required results, however if the t.id does not exist, the whole row is not returned. Is it possible to add some kind of parameter that says

`"If t.id does not exist then tpl_name = ''"` - so the row is returned, but the value of the tpl_name is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.img, p.template_usage, t.name as tpl_name
FROM platforms as p 
left join xml_template as t on t.id = p.template_usage
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue stems from the fact that you're using an implicit inner join in your query. Using a left join would be more apt for your situation.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.img, p.template_usage, t.name as tpl_name
FROM platforms as p
LEFT JOIN xml_template as t ON p.template_usage = t.id
```

I would suggest reading [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) as well as looking up what each SQL join accomplishes. [image: SQL joins]
<sub>(source: [geekphilip.com](http://www.geekphilip.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Join-Diagram.png))</sub>

Note: As John mentioned below, MySQL does not support a FULL OUTER JOIN.

There can be quirks between DBMSs when using some joins, however I would suggest knowing what each join type is trying to accomplish. Once you know how you want to join the tables, you will just need to look up how to accomplish it within your particular database.

Comment: you should actually try running these joins.. mysql doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: you are correct John; I included the picture more as a reference for explaining SQL joins rather than purely for MySQL. I will update my answer to include your feedback.

Comment: Yea I would just specify when showing that that it doesn't work in MySQL :)

Comment: not a problem! gotta give credit where credit is due! happy coding! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join.

```
select p.id, p.name, p.img, p.template_uage, t.name as tpl_name from platforms p left outer join xml_template t on p.template_uage=t.id;
```

A left outer join returns all rows from the left table regardless of whether there is a match in the right table. The corresponding columns from the right table that do not match the join condition show up as nulls.

Answer (score 0):

just as a side note.. use a `LEFT JOIN` to combine the tables whether there is matching or not... use `COALESCE()` for the null values from the left join.. you can specify anything you want to show up.. in this case I just added a blank space

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.name, 
    p.img, 
    p.template_usage, 
    COALESCE(t.name, ' ') AS tpl_name
FROM platforms as p 
LEFT JOIN xml_template as t 
  ON t.id = p.template_usage
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for an outer join

something like

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.img, p.template_usage, t.name as tpl_name 
  FROM platforms as p RIGHT OUTER JOIN xml_template as t 
    ON p.template_usage = t.id
```

Comment: @JohnRuddell Lol, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is synonymous for `RIGHT JOIN`.. although I believe a `LEFT JOIN` is in order here.